# Issue Installing and Configuring the ODBC Driver for macOS

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can successfully access Snowflake via `snowsql`, and a browser using the same credentials. However, those credentials do not work with the Driver as laid out in [odbc-mac](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html) guide. When I test according to "[Step 3: Test the ODBC Driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html#step-3-test-the-odbc-driver)" I get the following eperience:

```
$ "/Library/Application Support/iODBC/bin/iodbctest"

iODBC Demonstration program
This program shows an interactive SQL processor
Driver Manager: 03.52.1521.0607

Enter ODBC connect string (? shows list): dsn=SnowflakeDSII;pwd=[pwd]
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
OOB curl_easy_perform() failed: Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)

1: SQLDriverConnect = [Snowflake][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'SFRestRequestFailed' with message parameters ['[host]:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=[id]&request_guid=[guid]&databaseName=[db_name]&warehouse=[wh]&roleName=[role]', 'CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=77 msg='Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)' osCode=2 osMsg='No  (-1) SQLSTATE=HY000

1: ODBC_Connect = [Snowflake][DSI] An error occurred while attempting to retrieve the error message for key 'SFRestRequestFailed' with message parameters ['[host]:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=[id]&request_guid=[guid]&databaseName=[db]&warehouse=[wh]&roleName=[role]', 'CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=77 msg='Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)' osCode=2 osMsg='No  (-1) SQLSTATE=HY000
```

my `odbc.ini` file is

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
SnowflakeDSII = Snowflake

[SnowflakeDSII]
Server = [host account].[aws region].snowflakecomputing.com
UID = [user]
Role        = [role]
Database    = [db]
Warehouse   = [warehouse]
Driver = /opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib
```

Also...

- I installed the driver: `snowflake_odbc_mac_arm64-2.25.0.dmg`
- I had to manually `mkdir universal` and `cp lib/libSnowflake.dylib lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib`
- (And the error files too)

Thank you for your time!

### Update

Also note the system couldn't find the following error files:

```
  "exceptionMessage": "CURLerror (curl_easy_perform() failed) - code=77 msg='Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)' osCode=2 osMsg='No such file or directory'",
      "request":  "https://[host].us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=b5ebf406-989e-4aab-a043-6b4b656961cd&request_guid=8b68691f-db12-44c3-9a91-1fc685cd87a5&databaseName=[db]&warehouse=[wh]&roleName=[role]",
      "sqlState": "HY000"
```

- "/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/en-US/SFMessages.xml"
- "/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/SFMessages_en-US.xml"

So I `touched` them, but then the error said they were 'empty'

Comment: Can you enable [ODBC logging](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#ODBC) and see in the log what errors you get?

Comment: Thank you for your time and help! I updated the post and linked to a gist where I put the error logs for ease of reading.

Answer (score 5):

The issue was that many of the files that the system needs to be in `/lib/universal` are not there.

The solution is to either sym link, or move them from `/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc`

for example:

```sh
# I found
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/en-US/SFMessages.xml
```

in

```
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/ErrorMessages
```

Also

```sh
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/cacert.pem 

# needed to be moved to
/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/univeral/cacert.pem
```

*Thank you, @Sergiu for the logging guidance!*